# Is routing approach of Bitcoin Lighning Network "decentralized" and "trust-less"?

Tags: lightning-network, decentralization, trust, lightning-routing

From the [Bitcoin Lightning Network](https://lightning.network/):

> it is possible to find a path across the network similar to routing
>   packets on the internet.

Is routing approach of Bitcoin Lighning Network performed in a **"decentralized"** and **"trust-less"** manner ?

Also, the fact that in the Bitcoin network there is no **routing table** does not matter ?

Answer (score 1):

**Is routing decentralized and trustless:**

Generally, yes. It uses sphinx onion-routing to prevent any peer along the way to know origin/destination of payment.

Also note that Information of channel balances can leak if routing attempts are used to probe liquidity along a route.

Routing is not robust against sybil attacks, as compromised nodes can determine routes by reconstructing path via payment_hash in the htlc output scripts.

It is, however, incumbent upon the channel operator to ensure the lightning implementation is always synced with a full-node. Only this way can it detect a cheating channel counter-party and broadcast a penalty transaction. **Watchtowers may provide vigilance as a service but they are not trustless**

**Also, note that the lightning network is a separate p2p network.**

Discovering topology occurs with peers gossiping.

Comment: Thank you , Could you please say that if "separate p2p network" causes a kind of centralization or trust-based? If you could introduce a reference/paper/website on explanation of "separate p2p network" it would be perfect. Thanks

Comment: I cant really say that because there are no guarantees of centralization nor decentralization. Some argue liquidity for channels is expensive so it will aggregate in the hands of exchanges/individuals with high BTC accumulated. So nodes with high channel count activity will tend to have more payments touted though them, there may be a centralization pressure, yes. However, same goes with mining pooling and large merchants on the Bitcoin network.

Comment: You can say that Lightning is trustless in the sense that you can always penalize invalid channel closures (given you see them before the timeout).

Comment: Thank you , And is there a good reference explaining the term of _"**separate** p2p network"_ ? Thanks again

Comment: Sorry this is a little heavy but checkout the peer chapter in the lightning protocol rfc: https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc?files=1  Note that the lightning network “interfaces” with the Bitcoin network via Bitcoin transactions (open, commitments, close).

Comment: Do you mean this one? : https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/02-peer-protocol.md

Comment: Thats the p2p messaging protocol, yup.

Comment: Thanks , In this paper: (https://bit.ly/2RpuavY) it's claimed that: _"... belief is
that routing tables are necessary for large operators as for current Internet routing algorithms as BGP or Cjdns protocols. "_ AND: _"existence of a group of beacon nodes (even when selected randomly and renewed regularly) presents a threat to decentralization.  Indeed, even the global knowledge of the geometry of the network can be a vector of attack."_ Do you agree with this assertion? Thanks

Comment: Thats always the trade-off - a routing table via distributed hash table is slow, but decentralized. Central Beacons (even if somehow selected deterministically) are more performant, yet centralized.